# How to add comma in dropdown list values?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I try to build a dropdown list with PHPExcel (v1.7.9), but values with comma are not exported correctly

For example : if i want to export these two values : "12" and "5,9", the dropdown list I want is :

```
12
5,9
```

But i Obtain this :

```
12
5
9
```

And i found none answer on the web to this problem.

Have you an idea ?

```
$objValidation = $excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($nextLetter . $beginLine)->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
$objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Erreur');
$objValidation->setError('Cette valeur n\'est pas dans la liste');
$objValidation->setPromptTitle('Sélectionner la valeur :');
$objValidation->setPrompt('Merci de choisir une valeur dans la liste :');
$objValidation->setFormula1(/*????*/);
```

Comment: I don't know how your values are parsed. But you could try to escape the comma using a backslash `\`

Comment: 1.7.9 is rather dated, the current version is 1.8.1

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks, but the new version cannot fix the problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to have a series of cells containing the possible values, and set the formula to that range:

```
// Set cells containing our possible list values
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValueExplicit('A1', "12");
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValueExplicit('A2', "9,5");

// Set the data validation list
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell("B1")->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
$objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
$objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Erreur');
$objValidation->setError('Cette valeur n\'est pas dans la liste');
$objValidation->setPromptTitle('Sélectionner la valeur :');
$objValidation->setPrompt('Merci de choisir une valeur dans la liste :');
// Set the formula to the range of cells containing the list values
$objValidation->setFormula1('=A1:A2');
```

Another alternative would be to use a [Unicode full width comma](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0c/index.htm) between 9 and 5 using U-FF0C

Comment: Hi Mark, what is the correction notation to pass U-FF0C inside the string between 9 and 5? Could you write the setFormula1() argument here?